# SwiftData: "Could not conjure up a useful location for writing persistent stores."

Tags: swift-data

I have a SwiftData ModelContainer setup that defines a schema, a configuration, and a container using both.

While the app is running without problems in the simulator (which has iCloud not activated), the execution on a real device fails with this error message:

`CoreData: fault: Unhandled exception finding default Directory URL '+[NSPersistentCloudKitContainer defaultDirectoryURL] Could not conjure up a useful location for writing persistent stores.'`

It is accompanied by this information:

`Database located at: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/13FE17A8-8D88-4A1C-A50C-FBC93CE97718/Library/Application%20Support/" CoreData: error:  Failed to create directory`

This is independent of the fact if a ModelConfiguration is used or not - currently there is just this statement to create the container:

`return try ModelContainer(for: schema)`

I looked for this problem, but found no helpful information up to now.

I suspect the fact as relevant that the "enhanced iCloud security" is active on the device, and that this causes some additional procedures to be necessary, which I don't know, and which I could not find up to now.

Any ideas what's happening here?

=== Edit ===

In the meantime, I tried around a bit, and noticed other strange effects.

This code:

```
let url = URL.documentsDirectory.appending(path: "database.sqlite")
debugPrint("Database located at: \(url)")
let config = ModelConfiguration(url: url)
return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [config])
```

leads to this output:

```
"Database located at: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/867C00EA-DE25-4C18-A5DE-9FA4686C9E70/Documents/database.sqlite"
CoreData: error:  Failed to create directory file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/867C00EA-DE25-4C18-A5DE-9FA4686C9E70/Library/Application%20Support/: NSCocoaErrorDomain (513)
CoreData: fault: Unhandled exception finding default Directory URL '+[NSPersistentCloudKitContainer defaultDirectoryURL] Could not conjure up a useful location for writing persistent stores.'
```

This leads to the question: Does SwiftData simply ignore the given URL? And if so, under which circumstances?

This effect as well does not appear in the non-iClouded simulator.

Comment: I can not reproduce this using a custom url with an otherwise basic setup.

Answer (score -1):

Did your app in simulator use **Core Data** to store some data locally, and did you **download the container** from simulator and use it to **replace the container** on the real device?

I also got this problem today when I am running my app on a new iOS 17 device. I am not sure whether the local data is important to you, but if you don't care, you may simply remove the app by selecting the app name and clicking the `-` button from `Xcode --> Window --> Device and Simulator`, and reinstall the app again.